# getElementFromPoint(x,y) - whaaaat?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have *definitely* used this code before, but this time around it throws an error.

My code:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
  var getPoint = document.getElementFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY);
  alert(getPoint);
});
```

And I get the following **Error**:

```
document.getElementFromPoint is not a function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Firefox this function is called document.elementFromPoint()

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the method from : getElementFromPoint  , to : elementFromPoint and it is working fine in IE8 & latest firefox.